# How to delete old files in s3 to only keep the files for the current day - python + boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a S3 bucket, the folder structure looks like this:`bucket_name/year/month/day`, for each day, there are a couple of files in the corresponding folder.

For example, I have 10 files in `bucket_name/2021/09/05` and `bucket_name/2021/09/04`, 10 files in `bucket_name/2021/09/06` (current day is `2021/09/06`), how can I tell the code to look for files in the historical folders (except `bucket_name/2021/09/06` ) and delete them?

how can I add a step to look for the previous folders, hope this makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Any reason you want to do this via code, instead of creating a lifecycle rule in the bucket that would delete old files for you automatically?

Comment: If by code is a necessity for some reason, you can use `os.system('<aws cli commands>')` and pass the folder path with `--recursive` else @MarkB's comment should be the ideal way

Comment: Hi @MarkB It seems like I can apply lifecycle on a s3 prefix path, for my case, I only want to leave the files that are upoaded to the folder with the current day, if I set lifecycle to `expire current version actions` and `permanently delete preious version actions` with `1 day`, will s3 delete files 2 days or 3 days ago? Or it'll only delete the files one day ago?

Comment: If you set that lifecycle rule, it will delete all files older than one day.